# Finding the closest value in a vector, for each value in the same vector, excluding the element in question in R?

Tags: r, vector, nearest-neighbor, closest

I am trying to find a way to find the closest value in a vector, from elements in the SAME vector, but excluding the row in question. For example, suppose I have dataframe A with one column (column_1):

```
column_1
1
5
6
2
3
0
5
2
1
9
```

I want to add a second column which, for every element in column_1 finds the closest value in THAT SAME vector ***excluding*** the row in question. Desired output is below:

```
column_1    column_2
1           1
5           5
6           5
2           2
3           2
0           1
5           5
2           2
1           1
9           6
```

I have seen people discuss how to do this where the closest value for each element in a vector (a) is identified from ***another*** vector (b) via the following:

```
which(abs(a-b)==min(a-b))
```

Does anyone know how to modify the above, or do this in some other way, so that I can look within the same vector and exclude the row in question (example: the third row in column_1 is closest to 5 not 6, since I exclude its own row from the search vector. However, the fourth row in column_1 is closest to 2 since even when excluding the fourth row, there is another 2 value in the 8th row)

Comment: why is row 4 2 and not 1?

Comment: you say excluding the element in question but then why is row 1 1, or row 2 5?

Comment: I want to exclude the row in question. So, for element 4, I am looking in column_1 **except for** the fourth row. Since there is another value of 2 (in row 8), 2 is still closest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sort the vector, then check only the number before and number after, and replace the original vector:

```
y <- sort(x)
z <- c(-Inf, y, Inf)
b <- cbind(head(z, -2), tail(z, -2)) 
x[order(x)] <- b[cbind(seq_along(y), max.col(-abs(b - y)))]
x
[1] 1 5 5 2 2 1 5 2 1 6
```

---

Notice that this method has the lowest complexity as compared to the above solutions. Ie it is the fastest:

```
onyambu <- function(x){
  y <- sort(x)
  z <- c(-Inf, y, Inf)
  b <- cbind(head(z, -2), tail(z, -2)) 
  x[order(x)] <- b[cbind(seq_along(y), max.col(-abs(b - y)))]
  x
}

gregor <- function(x){
  dist = outer(x, x, FUN = \(a, b) abs(a - b))
  diag(dist) = Inf
  mins = max.col(-dist, ties.method = 'first')
  x[mins]
}
x <- rnorm(1000)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(onyambu(x), gregor(x), check = 'equal', times = 1)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 onyambu(x)    5.7839    5.7839    5.7839    5.7839    5.7839    5.7839     1
  gregor(x) 3021.9425 3021.9425 3021.9425 3021.9425 3021.9425 3021.9425     1
```

Comment: Sorting/ordering the vector a single time should speed it up. E.g., `z <- x[y <- order(x)]; y[y] <- z[seq_along(x) + 2L*max.col(-abs(z - cbind(c(Inf, z[-length(x)]), c(z[-1], Inf)))) - 3L]; y`

Answer (score 4):

```
# sample data
x = c(1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 0, 5, 2, 1, 9)

# make a distance matrix and set diagonal to Inf
dist = outer(x, x, FUN = \(a, b) abs(a - b))
diag(dist) = Inf

# find the index of the min value on each row
#   (which is the index of the max negative value
#    so we can use the convenient max.col)
mins = max.col(-dist)

# show the result
y = x[mins]
cbind(x, y)
#       x y
#  [1,] 1 1
#  [2,] 5 5
#  [3,] 6 5
#  [4,] 2 2
#  [5,] 3 2
#  [6,] 0 1
#  [7,] 5 5
#  [8,] 2 2
#  [9,] 1 1
# [10,] 9 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `get.knn` function from the `FNN` package:

```
x <- c(1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 0, 5, 2, 1, 9)
cbind(x, x[FNN::get.knn(x, 1)$nn.index])
#>       x  
#>  [1,] 1 1
#>  [2,] 5 5
#>  [3,] 6 5
#>  [4,] 2 2
#>  [5,] 3 2
#>  [6,] 0 1
#>  [7,] 5 5
#>  [8,] 2 2
#>  [9,] 1 1
#> [10,] 9 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way. Compute all distances from each element of the column to all other elements. To set the diagonal element to `Inf` is a trick to avoid index arithmetic. Then return the index to the minimum distance. This is used to assign the wanted values.

```r
df1 <- 
structure(list(
  column_1 = c(1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 0, 5, 2, 1, 9)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

i <- sapply(seq_along(df1$column_1), \(i) {
  d <- abs(df1$column_1[i] - df1$column_1)
  d[i] <- Inf
  which.min(d)
})
df1$column_2 <- df1$column_1[i]
df1
#>    column_1 column_2
#> 1         1        1
#> 2         5        5
#> 3         6        5
#> 4         2        2
#> 5         3        2
#> 6         0        1
#> 7         5        5
#> 8         2        2
#> 9         1        1
#> 10        9        6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I believe there is no need to compute the distance between the current element to all other elements. ie thats O(n^2) which is too expensive. You are repeating the computations. a - b and b-a. Also, note that if the vector is sorted, then you only need to compare the numbers in the position before and the after the current position,. No need to compute whole matrix distance. eg, check my solution above. Still voted (+1) for this solution

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dist` + `max.col` to locate the closest neighbor

```
> x <- c(1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 0, 5, 2, 1, 9)

> cbind(x, y = x[max.col(-`diag<-`(as.matrix(dist(x)), Inf))])
      x y
 [1,] 1 1
 [2,] 5 5
 [3,] 6 5
 [4,] 2 2
 [5,] 3 2
 [6,] 0 1
 [7,] 5 5
 [8,] 2 2
 [9,] 1 1
[10,] 9 6
```